# how to fix the associated script can not be loaded in unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

It says the associated script can not be loaded

[image]

I dont now how to fix it, please Help!

[image]

Comment: In general please don't post images of code .. copy&paste it here as **text** and format it as `code` via the `{ }` button.

Answer (score 0):

Hi The name of the class in line 5 Have to be the same name of the file.
And please write the first letter of the class name with camel case.
Replace NewBehaviurScript with MovePlayer2d and rename the file with the same name